# Bluetooth to serial device using Xamarin/Android

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin, serial-port

I'm attempting to write an application that can read and write to a device that accepts ordinary serial communication through a serial com port. I'm using a bluetooth to serial device. The bluetooth to serial device is a bolutek BK-MD-BC04-B_DEMO. It's basically a bluetooth device with a serial port on it.

I am able to connect to the device using my Android phone, and I can send data to it. With my computer connected to the serial port on the bluetooth device using PuTTY on COM5 with USB to serial, I can see the data I'm sending using my Android phone. I cannot seem to be able to get the serial commands to work properly when I connect the bluetooth adapter to my serial device, however. I am also unable to read anything back from the bluetooth adapter.

I have verified that all of the serial settings seem to be correct. The baud rate, data bits, stop bits, and parity are all set correctly on the bluetooth device.

I tried to contact bolutek via email, but they are very slow to respond. Here are some things I found on the device I'm trying to use:

http://www.electrodragon.com/w/index.php?title=BC04

http://docs.teguna.ro/BC04-electrondragon-2013-01-17.pdf

http://diwo.bq.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/BLK-MD-BC04-B_AT-COMMANDS.pdf

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using Android.Bluetooth;

//...

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private BluetoothSocket socket;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        EditText text = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

            Action finish = new Action(async delegate
            {
                if (socket == null)
                {
                    BluetoothDevice device = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices where bd.Name == "BOLUTEK" select bd).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (device == null)
                    {
                        AndroidMethods.message("Error", "BOLUTEK device not found. Please make sure you are paired with the BOLUTEK device.",
                            "OK", this);
                        return;
                    }

                    socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
                }
                if (!socket.IsConnected)
                    await socket.ConnectAsync();

                string outString = text.Text + "\r";
                string wakeString = "\t\r";

                byte[] output = charsToBytes(outString.ToCharArray());
                byte[] wakeUp = charsToBytes(wakeString.ToCharArray());

                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(wakeUp, 0, wakeUp.Length);
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(wakeUp, 0, wakeUp.Length);
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(wakeUp, 0, wakeUp.Length);
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(output, 0, output.Length);

                byte[] output2 = stringToBytes(outString);
                byte[] wakeUp2 = stringToBytes(wakeString);

                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(wakeUp2, 0, wakeUp.Length);
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(wakeUp2, 0, wakeUp.Length);
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(wakeUp2, 0, wakeUp.Length);
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(output2, 0, output.Length);

            });

            if (socket != null)
                finish();
            else if (adapter == null)
            {
                AndroidMethods.message("Error", "No bluetooth adapter found.", "OK", this);
                return;
            }
            else if (!adapter.IsEnabled)
            {
                DialogBuilder.createConfirmDialog(this, "Error", "Bluetooth adapter is not enabled. Would you like to enable it now?",
                    "No", "Yes", delegate
                    {
                        adapter.Enable();
                        finish();
                    });
            }
            else
                finish();
        };
    }

    public static byte[] stringToBytes(string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[value.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(value.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string bytesToString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }

    public static byte[] charsToBytes(char[] chars)
    {
        int length = chars.Length;
        byte[] returnVal = new byte[length];
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
            returnVal[x] = (byte)chars[x];
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

You'll notice I'm using two different methods of converting the string to a byte array. One of them just creates a char array and converts it to a byte array while the other converts a string array to a byte array and each byte is separated by a 0. Either method SEEMS to work when I am watching the incoming bluetooth to serial communication on my computer.

To communicate with the serial device, I would normally use PuTTY and hit tab then enter on my keyboard. This puts the serial device in command mode. You can do this multiple times. Thus the "\t\r". After you send a "\t\r", you should be able to enter a command followed by a "\r". So in PuTTY, I would enter on my keyboard something like "(tab)(enter)commandstring(enter)". The command I'm sending should change some settings on the serial device, yet when I connect to it through PuTTY, the settings are unchanged.

Is there anything I may be overlooking that could be causing this issue? I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and have yet to come up with a solution.